# Getting an error "Not a managed type: class java.lang.Long"

Tags: java, spring, jpa

In short, I try make authorization with Spring security. But I get error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class java.lang.Long

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'roleRepository': Invocation of init method failed;

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'roleRepository';
```

Interface RoleRepository implements methods from JpaRepository.

> https://github.com/TimurShubin/cbrparser/blob/master/src/main/java/com/cbr/converter/repositories/RoleRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface RoleRepository extends JpaRepository<Long, Roles>{

    @Query("select r from roles r where id = 1")
    public List<Roles> getRole(long userId);
    
}
```

It's associated with UserDetailsServiceImpl class, which implements loadUserByUsername method. In this method I getting user data (role, username, password).

I think that problem in entities classes (Roles, Users, UserRole), there I use OneToMany binding: UserRole consists user_id and role_id  fields, which associated with Users and Roles tables repsectively. I don't understand, where exactly is the error.

**UserRole:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_role")
public class UserRole {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private Users users;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", nullable = false)
    private Roles roles;

    // getters, setters

}
```

**Roles:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Roles {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    private Set<UserRole> roles;

    // getters, setters
}
```

**Users:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class Users {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long uid;
    
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;
    
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "enabled")
    private boolean enabled;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "users")
    private Set<UserRole> users;

    // getters, setters
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have `RoleRepository` class as below

```
@Repository
public interface RoleRepository extends JpaRepository<Long, Roles>{

    @Query("select r from roles r where id = 1")
    public List<Roles> getRole(long userId);
    
}
```

which needs to be changed as below because the the spring managed entity type `Roles` need to be the first argument.

```
@Repository
public interface RoleRepository extends JpaRepository<Roles, Long>{

    @Query("select r from roles r where id = 1")
    public List<Roles> getRole(long userId);

}
```